# Getting the first and last dates in a month

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two comboboxes that lets the user select a date and year.  What I want to do is to translate this into my query in access, which requires a [start date] and an [end date] parameter.

I.E. user picks "May" and "2013" in the combo boxes

My query is setup between [start date] and [end date], so I want to translate this month and year selection from the combo boxes into two strings (startdate and enddate, then pass them as command parameters) that contain MM/DD/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY.  What is the best way to take two strings and get the first valid day and last valid day.  I have:

```
FirstDayInMonth = DateSerial( _
 Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)

LastDayInMonth = DateSerial( _
 Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)
```

But I need to make the switch from a string into a date format to get back the first/last day of the selected month, using only the month ("MAY") and year ("2013")?  Am I missing something relatively simple?

Comment: Does your month combo box contains "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, do you get the month and year (as integer or long, not a date yet) from the comboboxes?
Then try this:

```
Dim m As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim d_from As Date
Dim d_until As Date

m = CLng("01") ' get these two from your comboboxes
y = CLng("2013") 
d_from = DateSerial(y, m, 1)

d_until = DateAdd("m", 1, d_from)
d_until = DateAdd("d", -1, d_until)
```

When you have the first date, you calculate the second (last day in month) by adding one month, then going one day back.

Answer (score 4):

Make the "Month" combo box have two columns (`Column Count` property is `2`):

```
 1 | Jan
 2 | Feb
...
12 | Dec
```

Set the `Bound Column` of the combo box to `1` so its `.Value` is the month number, but display only the month name (hide the number) by setting the width of the first column to zero:

```
Column Widths: 0";0.75"
```

Comment: +1. Multiple columns in combobox/listbox controls is *insanely* useful. Just hide the index values/etc and other stuff that you don't want the user to see.

Comment: We can get this number from `Combobox.ListIndex` without requiring an extra column. It is zero-indexed though, so we need to add 1.