# Get Fridays date in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i would like to get the Fridays date for current month
this is what i have in mind:

```
functionFindFriday()
if 1st friday then functionFindFriday = '6 dec 2013'
if 2nd friday then functionFindFriday = '13 dec 2013'
if 3rd friday then functionFindFriday = '20 dec 2013'
if 4th friday then functionFindFriday = '20 dec 2013'
end function
```

and i want to call it with

`functionFindFriday(1)` it will display '6 dec 2013'

`functionFindFriday(2)` it will display '13 dec 2013'

Comment: Please include attempted solutions and why they didn't work! Look into the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday` for a starting point!

Comment: Simple Formula:  =TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+8-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+2)+(N-1)*7.  In VBA: findFriday = Date - Day(Date) + 8 - Weekday(Date - Day(Date), vbFriday) + (N-1) * 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
Function FindFriday(nFriday As Integer) As Date
    Dim dateFirst As Date
    Dim dateNthFriday As Date
    dateFirst = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
    dateNthFriday = DateAdd("d", 7 * nFriday - Weekday(dateFirst, vbSaturday), dateFirst)
    If DateSerial(Year(dateNthFriday), Month(dateNthFriday), 1) <> dateFirst Then _
        Err.Raise 9999, , "There aren't " & nFriday & " Fridays in this month."
    FindFriday = dateNthFriday
End Function
```

Comment: you are my hero!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

In the `functionFindFriday()`,

- Get the [first day of the current month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324953/11683).
- Use `Weekday(that_day)` to learn what day of week it was.
- `DateAdd()` to `that_day` the number of days that separate `that_day` from a Friday (if `that_day` was `vbTuesday` then add 3).
- Start `DateAdd`ing 7 to the result of the above, getting another Friday each time, until a next result belongs to the next month.